# Como inverter a ordem dos rótulos em um gráfico de barras empilhadas com ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

estou tentando criar um gráfico com o seguinte código:

```
ggplot(data=percent.prod, aes(x=Ano, 
                          weights=Percent)) +
geom_bar(aes(fill=Tec), color="Black") +
geom_text(aes(x=Ano, y=Percent,  group=Tec, label=Percent),
        position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5),
        size=3.3,
        label=format(percent.prod$Percent, digits=2)
```

)

Meu problema é que os rótulos estão na ordem inversa das barras empilhadas, ou seja, como por exemplo para o ano de 2016 a ordem correta seria: começando de baixo para cima, 24.9, 28.3, 16.9, 24.4, 5.5.
Aproveito para perguntar como posso incluir o símbolo de percentual ao lado de cada rótulo?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Desde já muito grato.

Edit !!: O os dados utilizados foram:

```
dput(percent.prod[76:100,])
Tec = c("ATEC", "BTEC", "MATEC", "MBTEC", "NIND", "ATEC", "BTEC", "MATEC", "MBTEC", "NIND", "ATEC", "BTEC", "MATEC",  "MBTEC", "NIND", "ATEC", "BTEC", "MATEC", "MBTEC", "NIND", "ATEC",  "BTEC", "MATEC", "MBTEC", "NIND")

Ano = c("2012", "2012", "2012", "2012", "2012", "2013", "2013", "2013", "2013", "2013", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2015", "2015", "2015",
    "2015", "2015", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016")

Export = c(12564846472,  53788677033, 36940761522, 87101479257, 51906729735, 
       11396530944, 51624888795, 37156534710, 83970959768, 57626450284, 
       10756105955,   47718644439, 32898360367, 75602907330, 57858473283, 
       10334876386, 43303283493, 30138771177, 55457297725, 51612149166,
       10098074534,  45208104951, 31257070430, 52278633158, 46124081186)

Percent = c(5.18560344286623, 22.198977872998, 15.2457207143329, 35.9474134220715,
        21.4222845477314, 4.71368576675349, 21.3524189702076, 15.3682054359373, 
        34.7309825967206, 23.8347072303811, 4.78401062455662, 21.223898587527, 
        14.6322568952623, 33.6260272469666, 25.7338066456875, 5.4152855805679, 
        22.6901259320865, 15.7921630482135, 29.0586063626531, 27.043819076479,
        5.45942307518809, 24.4413101254115, 16.8988227402919, 28.2639205366434, 
        24.9365235224651)

percent.prod <- data.frame(Tec, Ano, Export,Percent)

colnames(percent.prod) = c("Tec",  "Ano", "Export", "Percent")
```

Comment: Para que possamos reproduzir a sua pergunta, adicionar uma parte dos seus dados usando a função `dput()`.

Comment: Esqueci de colocar. Já editei a pergunta e está no final uma parte do conjunto de dados. Desde já, muito obrigado.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Já consegui resolver o meu problema e vou compartilhar a minha solução:

```
ggplot(data=percent.prod, aes(x=Ano,y=Percent, fill=Tec, order = -as.numeric(Tec)  )) +
geom_bar(stat="identity", position = "stack", color="Black") +
geom_text(aes(x=Ano, y=Percent,  group=Tec, 
label=paste0(round(percent.prod$Percent,digits = 2),"%")), 
        size=3.3, position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5))
```

Answer (score 1):

Para inverter a order eu só adicionei um `-` antes de `Percent`. 
Para adicionar % depois dos valores, você pode usar a função `paste()`.

```
ggplot(data=percent.prod, aes(x=Ano, 
                          weights=-Percent)) +
geom_bar(aes(fill=Tec), color="Black") +
geom_text(aes(x=Ano, y=-Percent,  group=Tec, label=Percent),
        position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5),
        size=3.3,
        label=paste0(format(percent.prod$Percent, digits=2),"%")
        )
```